# Ending while loop using if

Tags: bash

Is there a way to end a while loop by using an if? Here's just some ***pseudocode*** of the basics of what I want to do:

```
re = 1
while [re = 1]
do
    echo "hello, enter name"
    read name
    echo name
    echo "continue? 1 for yes, 0 for no"
    read re
    if [re == 1]
    then
        pass
    elif [re == 0]
    then
        end while
    else
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use `continue` in place of `pass` if you want to skip the rest of the loop and start again from the beginning, and you need to use `break` instead of `end while` if you want to exit the loop altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bash supports the [`break`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html) command to do that:

```bash
 i=0; 
 while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do 
    if [ $i -eq 3 ]; then 
       break 
    fi
    echo $i
    let i++
 done
```

Will output:

```
 0
 1
 2
```